# Dateformat with Eval from database formatting

Tags: c#, .net

So I want a date formated like this 27/7. My code looks like this

```
<%# Eval("WStartDate", "{0:d/M}" ) %>
```

And the result is a date that looks like: 27-7.

How can I change this? I dont want to change my regional settings....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%# Eval("WStartDate", "{0:d'/'M}" ) %>
```

The reason why you get `-` instead of `/` is because the `/` character has a special meaning in a DateTime format: it represents the date separator in the **current** culture. If you want to display as literal you should escape it with single quotes: `'`.

---

UPDATE:

According to your comment it seems that you are using this Eval statement inside an ASP.NET server side tag to set some property such as a label text for example. In this case you could define the format as a separate variable:

```
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    string format = "{0:d'/'M}";
</script>
```

and then use it:

```
<asp:Label 
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("WStartDate", format) %>'
/>
```

Comment: Cool! I never knew how to escape that :) +1

Comment: Hmmm, I get Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Excellent help as always Darin! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is on some webserver.

You can modify the web.config to use another culture.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx